# VBA - Use selected range cells in standard excel functions

Tags: excel, vba, function, range, selection

New to VBA, been working on a macro, looking something like this:

```
Sub Test(): 
    Dim newRange as Range
    Set newRange = Selection
    Selection.Range("A1").Value = "x"
    Selection.Range("B1").Value = "y"
    Selection.Range("C1").Value = "z"

    Selection.Range("D1") = "=Sum(Selection.Range(A2) + Selection.Range(B2))"

End Sub
```

Where I can select any cell in the worksheet, use the macro, and then simply insert values to the cell A2 and B2 from my selection/seleciton range, and have the cell D1(also in from my selection range) be the sum of them.

So I can't make the above work, and I wonder if its even possible to make something like this. I know, that "" can't be used inside the

```
"=Sum(Selection.Range(A2) + Selection.Range(B2))"
```

that brings me an error, so is there anyway to make something similar to this?
Again,

```
Selection.Range("A1") = "=SUM(B1+C1)"
```

works, but I want the input in the sum function to be the B1 and C1 cells from my selection/selection range, and not just the B1 and C1 cells in the worksheet.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look into string concatenation. `= "SUM(" & Selection.Range(A2) & " + " & ...`

Comment: Note that `:` is an instructions separator token in VBA, as is.. a new line. As such, `Sub Test():{NEWLINE}` is entirely equivalent to `Sub Test(){NEWLINE}` - the colon is superfluous.